# what is the best solution for angular 4 mobile web solution

Tags: angular, mobile-website

I have an angular4 web application, and now I plan to provide mobile web solution to it. I googled a lot, there are ionic2/native script, but that mostly target mobile app solution and needs to use their own utility to generate the whole app.

My problem now is I want to reuse my current angular4 component as much as possible, while just add some mobile web solution, such as swipe, mobile styling, are there any solution that I can easily use to enhance my current angular4 web into mobile web ready solution?

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: a big question here is whether you want the app available in an app store, or whether a progressive web app (which could get a home screen icon, but comes from a browser) would be enough https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/?hl=en